# How to remove only sub category URL from magento

Tags: category, url-rewrite

I am using Magento for my eCommerce website

My current URL structure is:

example.com/parent-category/sub-category/page

I want a solution for the URL to be changed to :

example.com/parent-category/page

I just want to remove subcategory from the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it by **URL Rewrites**

1. Go to Magento 2 Admin -> Marketing -> SEO & Search -> URL Rewrites
2. Find the path by searching `Request path` column.
3. Change The Path same like example given below and save that.
4. Remove the cache `php bin/magento cache:clean`.
5. Refresh the front-end, click the main menu category then you can see the configured path.

Example Like :

Request path `parent-category/sub-category/page.html`

Modified path `parent-category/page.htm`

Comment: What To do when there are more then 500 categories there?